# Magento2 : How to Translate words of order pdf like subtotal,grand total

Tags: magento2, php, pdf, invoice-pdf

Magento,How to **Translate** words of **order pdf** like **subtotal**,**grand total**,**shipping & Handling** etc...

Where i have to work php files or phtml files or CSV ?

i need to translate that words in arabic .

Please check screenshots of Order PDF
https://prnt.sc/mtkbop

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your translation CSV file as :

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/i18n/{CSV_FILE_NAME(ex:en_US)}.csv
```

Enter the string you want to convert as :

```
"subtotal","Subtotal in Arabic"
```

Comment: ok trying to do this and let you know thanks

Comment: this is not working

Comment: admin PDF must be in arabic